# Handle multiple CVS repositories with emacs using PCL-CVS?

Tags: version-control, emacs, cvs, elisp

Is there a way to get PCL-CVS to operate on multiple CVS repositories at the same time? Each repository should get its own `*cvs*` buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A prefix arg bigger than 8 is needed. e.g.  `C-u C-u M-x cvs-update`

I found the answer in the Emacs manual.

cvs-examine is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `pcvs.el'.

Run a 'cvs -n update' in the specified DIRECTORY.
That is, check what needs to be done, but don't change the disc.
Feed the output to a *cvs* buffer and run `cvs-mode' on it.
With a prefix argument, prompt for a directory and cvs FLAGS to use.
A prefix arg >8 (ex: C-u C-u),
  prevents reuse of an existing *cvs* buffer.
Optional argument NOSHOW if non-nil means not to display the buffer.